# Better performance in this two table query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve the id's of the blogs from the users that sessionid follow:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
 WHERE id_usuario IN (SELECT toid FROM follows WHERE fromid = '$id')
```

This gives me the expected result but the performance is pretty bad even with a small number of rows.

Would I be better served with a join?

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *` -- only return the columns you absolutely need. Some of that wait time might be from the added network traffic of extraneous information in your query results.

Comment: True. Even if you need all columns, it's better to list what you want. That way you can add fields or change their order and your program still works.

Comment: It is really easy to rewrite it as a join. What results do you get with a join? Is it still slow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can quickly fix this by rewriting as:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id_usuario IN (SELECT toid FROM follows WHERE fromid = '$id' AND id_usuario = toid)
```

With your query, MySQL will try and materialize the outer query first (select all articles) and then filter based on the inner query, which is not efficient, unfortunately it's not smart enough right now to realise it should turn that subquery into a join.

You can give the optimizer the hint it needs though by referencing the outer table from the inner table on the condition you want to filter by, as I've done above.

Comment: Yep, a [correlated sub-query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) is the idea at work here.

Answer (score 3):

Even for a simple query like that, it would be very surprising if a join offered better performance.

The one thing I can suggest is an index on `id_usuario`.

Also, to analyse what the engine does with your query, use [Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html).